# Do likelihood-based confidence intervals avoid general criticisms of confidence intervals?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, likelihood, frequentist

In the literature, I see post-sample criticisms of frequentist confidence intervals — but the usual targets are intervals that use somewhat weak methods such as assumed normality or other long-run/asymptotic methods.

However, Bayesian credibility intervals simply average over a number of likelihood intervals.

If we construct an approx CI based on the likelihood function does this address the issues like post-sampling nonsense intervals?

Comment: Can you give some references for this "nonsense intervals"?

Comment: @thanks https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/12/11/fallacy-placing-confidence-confidence-intervals/